# Linking errors to the right field in WTForms FieldLists

Tags: python, ajax, wtforms, fieldlist

I am using WTForm to validate a form that I submit directly from a javascript model (filled through  knockout). In my form I have a list of bank accounts which can be added/removed dynamically. On the python side I have something like this :

```
class Account(Form):
    acc_name        = TextField('Account', [validators.Length(min=2, max=35)])    

class InformationForm(Form):
    account_list = FieldList(FormField(Account))
```

The json data that is received for validation is the following :

```
'account_list': [{'acc_name': 'aaaaa'}, {'acc_name': 'b'}]}
```

The problem is then when I validate I receive something like this where there is no way to know which account in the list is the source of the error:

```
'account_list': [{'acc_name': [u'Field must be between 2 and 35 characters long.']}
```

How can I do to link the error to the right account ?

**EDIT** : the way I did it in the end is that I added a getErrors method to my InformationForm class, which builds a dictionnary indexed by a unique Id for each Account where the values are each Account error. I then return that as json to my application. I keep the question open in case there is a "natural" solution...

Comment: Could you provide a link to your `getErrors` implementation? I don't believe there is a way to do this in WTForms itself, yet. I wish it'd return an error list like `[None, ["first error on second element", "second error on second element"], None]`.

Comment: I opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/issues/49) for this.

Answer (score 2):

Each individual element in a FieldList is a field in and of itself. If the FieldList contains a TextField, then each entry is a TextField. If it contains a FormField then it's a FormField (which then contains a form with its own fields) The FieldList entries can be accessed either by iterating a FieldList or by accessing the `.entries` attribute of the FieldList.

So instead of looking at `form.account_list.errors` look at the enclosed field's errors.

So for your use, something like this:

```
{% for subfield in form.account_list %}
    <!-- subfield in this case is an instance of FormField -->
    {{ subfield.form.acc_name() %}
    {% if subfield.errors %}
        {% for error in subfield.form.acc_name.errors %}
            <p class="error">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You probably want to [abstract this out to a macro](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.5/specific_problems.html#rendering-errors) instead of doing this for every specialty field setup, if this is something you need to do consistently and often.